# IIS 7.5 Rewrite Bug? Infinite loop

Tags: redirect, iis-7, iis-7.5, infinite-loop

We use IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite, with classic ASP.  Everything works properly 99% of the time, however, completely sporadic, pages of our site will fall into a redirect loop for no apparent reason.

Meaning, we have articles that render fine 99% of the time, but, like this morning, when accessing one article (out of thousands) the browser will respond with a "The page is not redirecting properly".  I use Firefox, but this occurs for all users in all browsers.  This also occurs on the site home page, and other pages, sporadically as well, so it doesn't appear to be related to a specific rewrite rule pattern, rather the rewrite rule engine as a whole.

Resetting IIS solves the problem immediately, and the page(s) load fine.  Resetting IIS seems to be the only way to fix this problem when it occurs.

IIS logs show 301 redirects for whatever page is affected.  In this case, one article page had thousands of 301 redirect log records.  Resetting IIS corrected the behavior.

Has anyone else had this issue, or any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: Is the browser being redirected to the same URL that was requested? Or is being redirected between two different URL's that redirect to each other?  Can you post your URL rewrite rules from your web.config?

Comment: Sorry, didn't receive notification of this comment. They redirect To the same URL, and I cannot post our web.config.  There is no common rewrite rule that applies, as they all differ (over 100 rules), so no specific rule.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I am experiencing similar behavior. A ASP.NET website is running fine 99% of the time, and then occasionally (twice over the last few months) the homepage of the site will start having an infinite redirect loop. Restarting IIS fixes the problem.

Comment: No.  It just went away and hasn't happened in a few months.  Could have been Windows updates.  Hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this, it was being caused by index.cfm being the first default document,  even though it was an Asp.net application and there was no index.cfm page.  Removing index.cfm from the default document list fixed the infinite loop.

Comment: Didn't see your comment.  index.cfm is not in the list.